# error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I did searching in the forum and checked there is no error NU1202 on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0.

I am trying to create a simple project with Blazor by using dotnet CLI.

Before running `dotnet new`, I run the dotnet new -i to install the Blazor template.

```
>dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
  Restoring packages for C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\restore.csproj...
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates 0.7.0.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 3.64 sec for C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\restore.csproj.

  Restoring packages for C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\restore.csproj...
  Installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates 0.7.0.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\obj\restore.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 873.93 ms for C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.202\scratch\restore.csproj.

Templates                                         Short Name            Language          Tags
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console               [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console
Class library                                     classlib              [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library
Unit Test Project                                 mstest                [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest
xUnit Test Project                                xunit                 [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit
Blazor (hosted in ASP.NET server)                 blazorhosted          [C#]              Web/Blazor/Hosted
Blazor Library                                    blazorlib             [C#]              Web/Blazor/Library
Blazor (Server-side in ASP.NET Core)              blazorserverside      [C#]              Web/Blazor/ServerSide
Blazor (standalone)                               blazor                [C#]              Web/Blazor/Standalone
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                   [C#], F#          Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                   [C#], F#          Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web App                              razor                 [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular               [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react                 [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux            [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi                [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI
global.json file                                  globaljson                              Config
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                             Config
Web Config                                        webconfig                               Config
Solution File                                     sln                                     Solution
Razor Page                                        page                                    Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports                             Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart                               Web/ASP.NET

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new nugetconfig
    dotnet new --help
```

Then start to create a new project:

```
>dotnet new blazor -o TestBlazorApp
The template "Blazor (standalone)" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj...
  Restoring packages for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj...
  Generating MSBuild file C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\obj\TestBlazorApp.csproj.nuget.g.props.
  Generating MSBuild file C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\obj\TestBlazorApp.csproj.nuget.g.targets.
  Restore completed in 1.27 sec for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.
  Restoring packages for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj...
C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj : error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
  Restore failed in 108.64 ms for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.

Restore failed.
Post action failed.
Description: Restore NuGet packages required by this project.
Manual instructions: Run 'dotnet restore'
```

Due to the error tried to run `dotnet restore`

```
C:\Blazor Quick Start Guide\Practice\Chapter01>cd TestBlazorApp

C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp>dotnet restore
  Restore completed in 49.71 ms for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.
  Restoring packages for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj...
C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj : error NU1202: Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0). Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Cli 0.7.0 supports: netcoreapp2.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.1)
  Restore failed in 136.22 ms for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.
```

However, I checked I have 2.1 SDK installed.

```
>dotnet --info
.NET Command Line Tools (2.1.202)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.202
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  281caedada

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.202\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.9
  Build    : 1632fa1589b0eee3277a8841ce1770e554ece037
```

What caused the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved.

Solution: 
 1. Install the latest 2.1 SDK from `https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.1`.　
 2. Install Blazor into the new SDK 
 3. Create a new project.

```
>dotnet --info
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.1.805
 Commit:    cee34dc8d6

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17134
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.805\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.1.17
  Commit:  7b9e4ef7c1

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  1.1.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.1.805 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.17 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET Core runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

C:\<PathToProject>dotnet new -i Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Templates
  Restore completed in 2.84 sec for C:\Users\XXXXXX\.templateengine\dotnetcli\v2.1.805\scratch\restore.csproj.

Usage: new [options]

Options:
  -h, --help          Displays help for this command.
  -l, --list          Lists templates containing the specified name. If no name is specified, lists all templates.
  -n, --name          The name for the output being created. If no name is specified, the name of the current directory is used.
  -o, --output        Location to place the generated output.
  -i, --install       Installs a source or a template pack.
  -u, --uninstall     Uninstalls a source or a template pack.
  --nuget-source      Specifies a NuGet source to use during install.
  --type              Filters templates based on available types. Predefined values are "project", "item" or "other".
  --force             Forces content to be generated even if it would change existing files.
  -lang, --language   Filters templates based on language and specifies the language of the template to create.


Templates                                         Short Name            Language          Tags
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Console Application                               console               [C#], F#, VB      Common/Console
Class library                                     classlib              [C#], F#, VB      Common/Library
Unit Test Project                                 mstest                [C#], F#, VB      Test/MSTest
NUnit 3 Test Project                              nunit                 [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit
NUnit 3 Test Item                                 nunit-test            [C#], F#, VB      Test/NUnit
xUnit Test Project                                xunit                 [C#], F#, VB      Test/xUnit
Razor Page                                        page                  [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewImports                                   viewimports           [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
MVC ViewStart                                     viewstart             [C#]              Web/ASP.NET
Blazor (hosted in ASP.NET server)                 blazorhosted          [C#]              Web/Blazor/Hosted
Blazor Library                                    blazorlib             [C#]              Web/Blazor/Library
Blazor (Server-side in ASP.NET Core)              blazorserverside      [C#]              Web/Blazor/ServerSide
Blazor (standalone)                               blazor                [C#]              Web/Blazor/Standalone
ASP.NET Core Empty                                web                   [C#], F#          Web/Empty
ASP.NET Core Web App (Model-View-Controller)      mvc                   [C#], F#          Web/MVC
ASP.NET Core Web App                              razor                 [C#]              Web/MVC/Razor Pages
ASP.NET Core with Angular                         angular               [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js                        react                 [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
ASP.NET Core with React.js and Redux              reactredux            [C#]              Web/MVC/SPA
Razor Class Library                               razorclasslib         [C#]              Web/Razor/Library/Razor Class Library
ASP.NET Core Web API                              webapi                [C#], F#          Web/WebAPI
global.json file                                  globaljson                              Config
NuGet Config                                      nugetconfig                             Config
Web Config                                        webconfig                               Config
Solution File                                     sln                                     Solution

Examples:
    dotnet new mvc --auth Individual
    dotnet new viewimports --namespace
    dotnet new --help

C:\<PathToProject>dotnet new blazor -o TestBlazorApp
The template "Blazor (standalone)" was created successfully.

Processing post-creation actions...
Running 'dotnet restore' on TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj...
  Restore completed in 3.56 sec for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.
  Restore completed in 2.22 min for C:\<PathToProject>\TestBlazorApp\TestBlazorApp.csproj.

Restore succeeded.
```